# Node inspector - debug-brk not breaking on first line

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I've installed node-inspector, and have started it with node.
When I try to start debugging mode with --debug-brk, it still errors out (it's this error I'm trying to debug)

It does not break on the first line...

$ node --debug-brk app.js

```
debugger listening on port 5858

/base_controller.js:59
        files.forEach(function(file) {
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.oncomplete (/base_controller.js:59:9)
```

Comment: bug? I made a file with some totally invalid js and called `node --debug-brk app.js`, and it stops, even without node-inspector started.

Answer (score -1):

installed node-inspector : `https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector`

**try below steps:**

first: node --debug-brk app.js

second:node-inspector

then:
open a new winow in chrome,open url:

```
http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
```

you can debug your code now !

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are not running the latest version (it happened to me). Please do

```
$ node
> process.version
```

That should give you the last version. You can update here: http://nodejs.org/